# Find text size for TextView

Tags: android, text, textview, size, font-size

I'm using a (horizontal) PagerView which shows 1 page on the screen, the user can switch pages by swiping left or right.
Every page holds several views in a RelativeLayout, one of them is a description text in a TextView (its size is calculated with weight).

I want the description text to be in the same font size for all pages.

This needs to be according to the longest description (the TextViews in all the pages are in the same height).

I have an array of all the descriptions in advance but I don't have rendered TextViews since they are in different pages and android won't draw it until scrolled to the page.

Any idea how the correct font size could be calculated?

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but would this do the job?
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html

Comment: It won't make all TextViews the same size

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution so just sharing.
This is easily implemented using StaticLayout. When creating StaticLayout you assign its width and can check its height (it will automatically start the text in a new line if it's too long).
Just iterate over your "texts array", for every line of text create a StaticLayout with your desired width and make sure it's height fits inside your TextView height, if not, decrease the font size and recheck. You'll eventually get the largest font size that fits the TextView size.

Answer (score 0):

Get the 1st textview text size & typeface. Then set that size and typeface to other textviews. Or you can get height & width of the textview & set that to others.

```
        float size = textView1.getTextSize(); //get the size of the textview text
        textView2.setTextSize(size) //set the size for other textview's texts

//if you want look in same size, all text must have same TypeFace(Font). To do that use.
        textView1.getTypeFace();
        textView2.setTypeFace();

//or you can get hight & width of the textview.    
    textView.setText("GetHeight");
    textView.measure(0, 0);       //must call measure!
    textView.getMeasuredHeight(); //get height
    textView.getMeasuredWidth();  //get width

//set textview height & width
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 70;
    params.width = 100;        
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I don't want to make all other TextViews like the first one, I want to calculate the maximum font for the TextView by the longest text, then apply the font to all TextViews, which most of them are not rendered yet, only when I swipe the PagerView